# before install: CodeDeploy agent was not able to receive the lifecycle event. Check the CodeDeploy agent logs on your host and make sure the agent is

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I have set up a pipeline, but i get the following error during deployment:

```
before install CodeDeploy agent was not able to receive the lifecycle event. Check the CodeDeploy agent logs on your host and make sure the agent is running and can connect to the CodeDeploy server.
```

Code Agent is running, but i do not know, what the problem is. I checked the logs of codedeploy:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-255-11 ~]$ sudo cat /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log
2022-09-27 00:00:02 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3694)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 45.14352 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:632547665100:instance/i-01d3b4303d7c9c948")  

2022-09-27 00:00:03 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3694)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.4.0-2218_rpm.
2022-09-27 00:00:03 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3694)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version with agent version OFFICIAL_1.4.0-2218_rpm.
```

Answer (score 6):

Also was unlucky enough to meet this problem today.

Please use [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html#deployments-view-logs-instance) and look at the CodeDeploy agent logs of your compute platform instance (EC2, probably).

in my case, it turned out that I did not have an AppSpec file added to the project.

Comment: in my case the format of the .yml was wrong. I wasn't to find the error

Answer (score 6):

AWS error messages may not adequately interpret the errors encountered. One likely case is iam permission issues. Make sure CodeDeploy has CodeDeployRole and your EC2 instance(s) have AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy.

Answer (score 2):

I got this as error from codedeploy:
Message
CodeDeploy agent was not able to receive the lifecycle event. Check the CodeDeploy agent logs on your host and make sure the agent is running and can connect to the CodeDeploy server.

In my case, I had a deployment group, that had a tag, with no corresponding EC2 machine. I had created a new deployment group with a corresponding EC2 machine, but I did not change the group in the pipeline. After changing to the right deployment group, it worked. Hope this helps someone.

My codedeploy agent never received anything, that is why it is shown the information about the version.

In my opinion, this error message could be greatly improved from AWS side.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't have an Instance Profile (role) attached to my EC2. When I attached the role, it still wouldn't work and I was still getting permission errors under `/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log`. I tried rebooting the instance and finally the deployment succeeded. Perhaps restarting the agent instead of the instance would have been enough.

As for the Role's permissions, I believe attaching the `AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy` policy was enough to get it to work.

Comment: Hi, may I ask how did you attach the policy to the instance?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was a #nextjs app. My mistake was having codebuild copy just the build directory (`out/`), leaving out `appspec.yml` and the script files.

Changes I made to fix it:

in buildspec.yml:

```
...
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
  base-directory: "./"
```

in appspec.yml:

```
...
files:
  - source: "./out"
    destination: "/var/www/html"
```