# Unable to deploy via CodeDeploy

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am currently trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline. I created a Code Build and it's in s3. I am now using CodeDeploy to deploy it to an EC2 instances. When I try to deploy I get this error immediately

`CodeDeploy agent was not able to receive the lifecycle event. Check the CodeDeploy agent logs on your host and make sure the agent is running and can connect to the CodeDeploy server.`

I found suggestions here [before install: CodeDeploy agent was not able to receive the lifecycle event. Check the CodeDeploy agent logs on your host and make sure the agent is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73861102/before-install-codedeploy-agent-was-not-able-to-receive-the-lifecycle-event-ch)

I've made sure CodeDeploy has CodeDeployRole and AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy

[image]

I've checked that CodeDeploy is on my EC2 instance.

Unfortunately I still can't deploy. Any tips or suggestions would help

Comment: Try asking your manager to see if they have the correct permissions for you. it seems most AWS issues are permission issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when I changed the ec2 `role`, [I had to restart codedeploy agent](https://devopspilot.com/content/aws/issues-faced.html)